# How to draw a mapping with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

So I would like to have a graphic for a mapping g on an arbitrary dihedral group from the n-1-2 vertex to some arbitrary other vertices using TikZ. Right now I have a pretty crappy drawing I made in Paint which I will attach to show what I'm going for. Any help would be appreciated. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options, depending on the desired arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\draw
  (0,0) node[above] {$n$} -- 
  ++(45:1.5cm) node[above] {$1$} -- 
  ++(0:1.5cm) node[above] {$2$};
\node[label={above:$g$}] at (4,0.5) {$\Rightarrow$};
\draw
  (5,0) node[below] {$i+1$} -- 
  ++(10:1.5cm) node[below] {$i$} -- 
  ++(50:1.5cm) node[right] {$i-1$} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with a single arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\draw
  (0,0) node[above] {$n$} -- 
  ++(45:1.5cm) node[above] {$1$} -- 
  ++(0:1.5cm) node[above] {$2$};
\node[draw,single arrow,label={above:$g$},text width=1cm] at (4,0.5) {};
\draw
  (5.5,0) node[below] {$i+1$} -- 
  ++(10:1.5cm) node[below] {$i$} -- 
  ++(50:1.5cm) node[right] {$i-1$} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Example (with the arrow part set in math):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\[
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \tikz\draw[thick, node font=\scriptsize]
      (-135:1) node[above left] {$n$}
      -- (0, 0) node[above left] {$1$}
      -- (1, 0) node[above] {$2$};%
  }}
  \stackrel{g}{\Rightarrow}
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \tikz\draw[thick, node font=\scriptsize]
      (-190:1) node[below] {$i+1$}
      -- (0, 0) node[below] {$i$}
      -- (45:1) node[right] {$i-1$};%
  }}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The construct `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}` just centers the material `...` vertically according to the current math axis.